Best (balancing speed/accuracy) way of computing this function from Marden (1982)?
TL;DR: What's the best "modern" way to approximate the function below, using R?
In Marden (1982), this function is defined (4.2, p. 272):
$$r(\nu, \mu)=\inf \left\{s>0 \left\lvert\, \inf _{z>0} \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \frac{\partial}{\partial z^s} \log {}_1F_1(z ;(\nu+\mu) / 2, \nu / 2) \geq 0\right.\right\}$$
and they've shown (Marden and Perlman, 1982) that $\max (1 / 2, \nu /(\nu+\mu))<r<1$.
I've translated the FORTRAN code in the appendix of Marden and Perlman (1982, p. 178) to approximate this function into R (for even $\nu,\mu$), and I can reproduce their table of values (p. 148) so I know it works (at least partially).
The gist of the R code can be found here: https://gist.github.com/richarddmorey/c80ab1ea10d2eef14dca6a8149b81468.
They describe the code (Marden and Perlman, 1982, p. 176):

The function $\operatorname{RSTAR}(\nu, \mu)$ calculates $r(\nu, \mu)$ for $\nu$ and $\mu$ even as follows. Using the method of inverse linear interpolation, iterate until $z_0$ is obtained where $\left|\operatorname{DT}\left(\nu, \mu, z_0\right)\right| \leq 5 \times 10^{-10}$, and set $\operatorname{RSTAR}=\operatorname{T}\left(\nu, \mu, z_0\right) . \quad$ By inverse linear interpolation to find a root of $q(z)$, we mean iterate
$$\quad z_{i+1}=z_i-q\left(z_i\right)\left(z_i-z_{i-1}\right) /\left(q\left(z_i\right)-q\left(z_{i-1}\right)\right)$$
until $\left|q\left(z_{i+1}\right)\right| \leq \varepsilon$.

(further explanation of the individual functions can be found starting on page 175; e.g., the function zeroF0 approximates ${}_1F_1$.)
My question is: what's the best way to approximate the function $r(\nu,\mu)$, using the functions and packages available in the R ecosystem?

Marden, J. I. (1982). Combining Independent Noncentral Chi Squared or $F$ Tests. The Annals of Statistics, 10(1), 266–277. https://doi.org/10.1214/aos/1176345709

Marden, J. I., & Perlman, M. D. (1982). The minimal complete class of procedures for combining independent noncentral $F$-tests. In S. S. Gupta & J. O. Berger (Eds.), Statistical Decision Theory and Related Topics III (pp. 139–181). Academic Press. https://doi.org/10.1016/B978-0-12-307502-4.50014-3


